# How to let users log in using Drupal default login when they used a custom join module?

Tags: users

We have two ways to join and log in the site:

1 - Via the university authentication module (it is a third party authentication module that I cannot update). It requires a username (not an email address) and a password.

2 - Register with email address, receive one-time login link, set password (Drupal default module).

How can I have the first type of users (who used the university authentication module to join) also login with an email address and password without using the university authentication module?

I am using Drupal 7.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the "university authentication" module?  Is that a custom module you cannot or don't want to modify?

Comment: Thanks @GaëtanFrenoy - I updated the description. It is a third party authentication module that I cannot update.